# Is there a good IE-based Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, web-testing

The SeleniumIDE project is based on Firefox (and its plugin architecture).  My  application (for a variety of reasons)  only runs on Internet Explorer (6+).  In fact, we actively check for non-IE browsers and do an immediate redirect.

*This is a 6 yr old codebase and we're trying to remove all of the html idiosyncrasies that necessitate our IE dependence.*

We've already got a robust and growing set of NUNIT tests for code.  We would like to add Selenium to do Web functional testing.  Is there a good IDE for building/recording Selenium tests using IE as the browser?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Selenium does not have an IDE for Internet Explorer (any version).  I haven't seen any under development either.  You can check their [boards](http://clearspace.openqa.org/community/selenium)/[site](http://seleniumhq.org/) for updates but I their primary focus is FireFox for the IDE.

Selenium can run tests in Internet Explorer (including IE6) using the [SeleniumRC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/). You can record tests with the IDE in FireFox (or write tests in [whatever language they support](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html)) and then use SeleniumRC to launch IE and run the tests.

For Internet Explorer IDEs similar to what Selenium gives in FireFox, check out [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I'll explore it, but for now, this answer is non-responsive to the question isn't it?  Unless I'm missing something WatiN generates its own C# code and doesn't generate Selenium tests.

Comment: Maybe you can consider it as, "I don't know, but here's something that may help."  I wouldn't call it non-responsive.

Comment: Sorry.  In the contracting world, when responding to an RFP for example, if you don't answer the questions/requirement but kind of redirect to something else that you have more experience with, its called being "non-responsive" to the requirements/question.  That's the sense I was using it in.

Comment: Sorry I mis-read the question.  I thought you were looking for an IDE similar to Selenium for IE.  There is no IE IDE for Selenium that I'm aware of.

Comment: +1 for "Selenium does not have an IDE for Internet Explorer (any version)" which, I think, is answering the question asked.

Comment: There are still no plans to write an IDE for IE as of early 2011.

Source: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=563

Answer (score 3):

While not a Selenium recorder, this is a [utility](http://code.google.com/p/fire-ie-selenium) that will help in writing code that uses Selenium to drive a web application or web site that only works in IE.

The utility will help retrieve the locator strings that are used in the Selenium APIs to refer to elements in the DOM.

Comment: To be a useful answer I would include some specific information about the link - like that it still isnt a true recorder - just a helper utility for someone building Selenium scripts

Comment: Yes this is not at all a selenium recorder. It is just helps for identifying locator Id/Name/Xpath. Sorry for not providing information.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but there is a product called testmaker which does exactly what you are looking for.  The company was purchased, and it looks like there new products are no longer free, but there are still links to the free community edition of testmaker on their site

http://www.pushtotest.com/testmaker-6-community-download

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but i would like to add another solution, i said this on the Selenium IRC and no one knew it was possible. Anyway, there's another way of automating on IE using the old FF IDE(2.9.1), and that's how I'm currently automating on IE8. Prerequisites:

-FF 54 or older

-Selenium IDE 2.9.1

-selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar

-IEDriverServer

Start the selenium server with the following command on the windows cmd(press windows key+R and write cmd):

```
java -jar c:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverServer.exe
```

In this example, my files where in c:\selenium, so adapt to it to where you have the files. Once the server is up, open the FF IDE, go to the options, in the last tab "WebDriver", mark the option "Enable WebDriver Playback", and in the field bellow, delete all if there's any text in it and write:

```
internet explorer
```

Save the changes. Now you can run your tests in the IE. Note that you can't record or execute single commands of your scripts this way on IE, this only allows you to run your scripts on IE. You can record them on FF and them run it on IE.