# Free Tool(s) / Tips to assist me in filling out forms on Win7?

Tags: firefox, testing, automation, google-chrome

I am doing some web development on some long forms.  There are many fields for me to fill out to get through the form.

Instead of typing out the same things every time (contact information, address, business information) I'm hoping there is some tool out there / combination of tools that will assist me in filling this out.

Requirements: 
I am doing development / testing in FF, IE, and Chrome on a Win 7 system, so the tool would leverage one of those platforms.  Oh yeah, one more thing: It's got to be free and lightweight, otherwise, I'd rather just type out responses to the form fields.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/) too.

Answer (score 0):

[Roboform](http://www.roboform.com) would be a good choice.  It works in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use IRobotSoft free software if you prefer a development style.  It works for IE only though.

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox I really like Selenium IDE. 
But I am afraid there's not a tools common to each browser.

For Chrome, I read that [iMacros](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp) can replace Selenium but not fully.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972717/is-there-a-good-ie-based-selenium-ide) can help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my chrome extension [Formbot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formbot/ilnjaomgpkbmapjachcppgabkidbmnjc), you can either set up fields to be populated with random valid data or else a preset value.