# Cross Browser testing: is there a way to run and control multiple browsers at the same time?

Tags: css, testing, cross-browser

Testing a large website for CSS mistakes can be daunting, especially when you have to repeat the same actions over and over again across all the different browsers. So, I wonder if there is a way to control different browsers at the same time, executing the same clicks and scrolls at the same time throughout all open browesers?

Say, I have two screens, 2 browsers are each vertical half of the screen, being able to control all 4 of them would tremendously speed up the time it takes and the quality of testing.

Is this feasible at the moment? has someone written a program to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the easiest thing in the world, but you can use Selenium IDE to automate browser tasks in many browsers:
http://seleniumhq.org/

You need to set-up Selenium Remote-Control. Never done this myself so I don't know exactly what's involved:
http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972717/is-there-a-good-ie-based-selenium-ide

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend [Adobe BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html#) for this. It let's you pull up instances of your site into several browsers at once and offer tools for comparing css cross-browser. Plus it's free, you just have to make an account with Adobe.

Comment: A note for historical purposes: Adobe BrowserLab shut down on Mar 13, 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft's Expression product they have the "Super Preview". It's a simple side by side comparision tool but as far as I know it wont automate clicks like you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

For simple tasks you may want to try http://tuttijs.com/

However, in order to execute clicks and stuff, you probably need to combine that with Selenium Core. (Or rely on SeleniumRC as mentioned above)